# The member 'Player.GameID' has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

Error message:
The member 'Player.GameID' has no supported translation to SQL.

LINQ:

```
 foreach (Table ta in custQuery)
        {
            if (ta.Gameform_string.ToLower() == "pineapple")
            {
                //Add the table
                Tables.Add(ta.GameID, ta);

                //Add player to seats
                Table<Player> p = db.GetTable<Player>();

                IQueryable<Player> playerQuery =
                from Seat in p
                where Seat.GameID == "ASD"
                select Seat;

                foreach (Player player in playerQuery)
                {
                    ta.AddSeat(player);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I remove Seat.GameID == "ASD" all the other fields gets loaded without any problem.

In the player Class I have this code:

```
[Column(Name = "GameID", Storage = "gameID")]
    private string gameID;
    public string GameID { get { return gameID; } set { gameID = value; } }
```

This thread mentions that LINQ needs to know to where it is mapped, which it is in my case as far as I can see it:
[The member [class] has no supported translation to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893646/the-member-class-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql)

If I run the program without the where clause I can see that the player class gets created with the gameID value:

```
        gameID  "ASD"   string
    GameID  "ASD"   string
```

Comment: What specific line is throwing the error?  I think that you should change `from Seat in p` to `from s in p` so as not to confuse the compiler since it may thing that `Seat` is an object of type `Seat` and not a variable name.

Comment: Hi, I changed it from Seat to s but no luck. The error is thrown on this row: "foreach (Player player in playerQuery)"

Comment: Instead of using `IQueryable<Player>` use `List<Player>`.  Tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `[Column(Name = "GameID", Storage = "gameID")]` attribute must be applied to the public `GameID` property and not to the `gameID` private field.